# Dumping values in Windbg and padding

Tags: c++, c, debugging, windbg

I am dumping a class in Windbg (by `dt`) and for a `bool` member I see the value `fffffffffffffff8`  (bin: ...1111111111111111000). **It is a valid value (including padding) or not?**

PS: i'm investigating a dump that may be a memory corruption so .. can't be sure.
PS2: my bool is in class between a `pointer` and a `size_t`. Compiled as release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a valid `bool` value -- `bool` should only show up as `0` or `1`. Since you're seeing 0xf8, the memory is either not initialized or overwritten. (Note that for some reason, WinDbg will only read a single byte and then sign-extend it to 64-bits.)